# Netbeans: How to specify the width of JLabel?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jlabel

I am developing a small application in Java. On my UI i place a jPanel and put a JLabel in it. The size of panel grows and shrink according to my application window size.

Now i want to set the width of my JLabel to half of that JPanel. i.e my JLabel starts from beginning of that JPanel and goes to the middle of that JPanel. How should i achieve this?

Edit:
I also want to place another JLabel in front of the above JLabel which starts from the middle of JPanel and goes to the end of JPanel

Comment: What layout do you use and what is the container of the jlabel?

Comment: @roni the container for JLabel is JPanel, i am sorry i am new to java so i don't know what you mean by layout i am using

Comment: What IDE are you using, if any? **Edit** Sorry, I see that you've tagged this as a NetBeans question.  Are you using the GUI builder?

Comment: Jame, the solution (as roni intimated) is to learn about the layout managers available to Swing and to use the right combination of managers to achieve the layout desired. Please look here: [Visual Guide to Layout Managers](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)

Comment: @JonathanSpooner *"Are you using the GUI builder?"*  That won't help unless/until the developer understands the Java layouts (see the link from HFOE).  When they *do* understand them, the GUI builder becomes a distraction, good only for prototyping mock-ups.

Comment: BTW - I find your description confusing.  Can you rough it out in ASCII art?  It would also be helpful if you can show two views, the second demonstrating how/where extra space (as the GUI is resized) should be assigned.

Comment: @AndrewThompson true, I was jumping the gun

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Design some HTML that neatly divides the text into two halves - a table with one row and two cells would probably do the trick.  Then stick that entire HTML into **one** label.

Comment: @JamesGoodwin Yeees!  (That is the most intelligent reply I can muster to your vague, drawn out enquiry.)

Comment: I don't like it (please ignore that my view), in other hands works, bump +1

Answer (score 3):

The default layout of `JPanel` is `Flowlayout`, which uses the label's preferred size—just big enough to hold the text. Instead, use `new GridLayout(1, 0)` to get one row with equal sized columns. Add your label followed by a second, empty label. Use `setOpaque()` and `setBackground()` to see the effect.

Several commenters correctly observe that using NetBeans' GUI design tool may be premature. It's a tool, not a panacea. Start by learning [layouts](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html). Paradoxically, one way to learn is to explore layouts in the designer itself. Just right-click on the relevant layout in the `Inspector` panel and choose `Set Layout`.

Comment: @trashgod: Am i able to change layout though Netbeans UI or i have to code for that?

Comment: I've elaborated above. Snide maxim: Using a Smith-Corona doesn't make one a novelist. :-)